# Not able to select option in context menu in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

How do I select options from a context click / context menu?

I am able to perform right click on the particular element, but not able to select any option. Below is my code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "https://www.flipkart.com";
IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
ele.SendKeys("shoes");
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
a.ContextClick(ele).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowUp).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Perform();
```

Comment: which context menu ? are you trying to click any option coming after entering text shoes ?

Comment: It looks like you are just getting your feet wet with selenium. There is no need to go through all of the send key commands like that.Just do another driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("path")).click;

Comment: when we perform right click in webpage a context menu will be appear with options if i need to select any option from the context menu i will select or click  the option with mouse . for eg: you navigate to stack overflow web site and you perform a right click on webpage  and context menu appears from context menu  say if we click  on print  . the same how can we do in selenium with c#